# Attempt to Iterate through javascript array only affecting first element

Tags: javascript, wordpress, loops

I am trying to create a dropdown menu in javascript/css, the method I have works but only on the first element.

I'm thinking the solution here is to change subLinkUl to a querySelectorAll and nest a loop inside of the navLink loop. I've tried accomplishing this but still relatively inexperienced with javascript.

The html list is printed dynamically through wordpress.

```
<div class="sidenav-link-wrap">
        <h2>Title 1</h2>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'side-menu-services', 'container_class' => 'sidenav-links') ); ?>

        <h2>Title 2</h2>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'side-menu-about', 'container_class' => 'sidenav-links' ) ); ?>
</div>
```

```
const navLink = document.querySelectorAll(".sidenav-links>ul>li");
    console.log(navLink);

    navLink.forEach((link, index) => {
        let subLinkUl = link.querySelector("ul");

        if (link.contains(subLinkUl)) {
            link.classList.add("dropdown");
        }

        const subLinkUlHeight =
            parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(subLinkUl).height) + "px";
        subLinkUl.style.marginTop = "-" + subLinkUlHeight;

        link.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
            subLinkUl.style.opacity = "1";
            subLinkUl.style.marginTop = "0";
            subLinkUl.style.transition =
                "margin 0.2s ease-in-out, opacity 0.1s ease-in 0.1s";
        });
        link.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
            subLinkUl.style.opacity = "0";
            subLinkUl.style.marginTop = "-" + subLinkUlHeight;
            subLinkUl.style.transition =
                "margin 0.2s ease-in-out 0.1s, opacity 0.1s ease-in";
        });
    });
```

```
.sidenav-link-wrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(min-content, max-content);
    padding: 110px 2vw 0px;
    text-align: left;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.sidenav-link-wrap h2 {
    padding: 25px 0px 15px;
}
.sidenav-links a {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0px;
}

.sidenav-links ul {
    transition: margin 0.2s ease-in-out, opacity 0.1s ease-in 0.1s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sidenav-links > ul > li {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sidenav-links > ul > li a,
.sidenav-link-wrap > a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #501622;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.sidenav-links > ul > li a::before,
.sidenav-link-wrap > a::before {
    content: "";
    background-image: url(../images/bullet-arrow.svg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    vertical-align: -22.5%;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: -25px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.sidenav-links > ul > li a:hover::before,
.sidenav-link-wrap > a:hover::before {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.sidenav-links .dropdown > a::before {
    background-image: none;
}

.sidenav-links .dropdown > a:hover::before {
    margin-left: -25px;
}

.sidenav-links .dropdown > a::after {
    content: "";
    background-image: url(../images/bullet-arrow-var-02.svg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    vertical-align: -20%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.sidenav-links .dropdown ul li a {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.sidenav-links .dropdown ul li > a::before {
    background-image: url(../images/bullet-arrow-var-02.svg);
    background-size: 15px 15px;
    vertical-align: -45%;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.sidenav-links ul li ul {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: You might be overthinking this a bit. Purely from a simplistic standpoint, I would toggle the elements with CSS `:hover`.
If for some reason, you need the toggled element to stay open after a click, I would add a class to the parent element and handle it like that.

Comment: @Frizzant I need to use javascript because the list items are added dynamically. As of right now the if contains statement only applies to the first element that contains sublinkUl. There are multiple elements that should fit this conditional statement and that is what the question is pertaining to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was correct the solution was to nest a for loop for the subLinkUl within the navLink foreach loop and pass the i index from there.

```
const navLink = document.querySelectorAll(".sidenav-links>ul>li");

    navLink.forEach((link, index) => {
        const subLinkUl = link.querySelectorAll(".sub-menu");

        for (let i = 0; i < subLinkUl.length; i++) {
            if (link.contains(subLinkUl[i])) {
                link.classList.add("dropdown");

                const subLinkUlHeight =
                    parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(subLinkUl[i]).height) +
                    "px";
                subLinkUl[i].style.marginTop = "-" + subLinkUlHeight;

                link.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
                    subLinkUl[i].style.opacity = "1";
                    subLinkUl[i].style.marginTop = "0";
                    subLinkUl[i].style.transition =
                        "margin 0.2s ease-in-out, opacity 0.1s ease-in 0.1s";
                });
                link.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
                    subLinkUl[i].style.opacity = "0";
                    subLinkUl[i].style.marginTop = "-" + subLinkUlHeight;
                    subLinkUl[i].style.transition =
                        "margin 0.2s ease-in-out 0.1s, opacity 0.1s ease-in";
                });
            }
        }
    });
```